# Who was the attacker targeting in episode 1?

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

Who was the man with the knife targeting or trying to attack in episode 1?

He didn't really stop, he just left the knife and kept going.  Was this a random event?  Kind of like a drive-by?

Did the attacker want to kill a random person?

Answer (score 7):

**Who was the attacker targeting in Episode 1?** No one in particular, the attacker was just a random criminal. In the light novel,

> the man had 'a backpack in one hand and a kitchen knife in the other.' After Satoru was stabbed, as stated in the light novel, the man  *ran off* shouting:  “Get the hell outta my way!” (**Volume 1**).

While the man was made to look like just a random guy sprinting in to attack Satoru in the anime, the light novel was more specific. From this, it can be said that *the man is a criminal or a thief* (as he has a backpack but is not wearing it over his back, which he probably stole hurriedly). Also, the man yelled to get out of his way, meaning *he was in a hurry trying to get away from someone or something*.

The wiki [synopsis](http://tensura.wikia.com/wiki/Light_Novel_Volume_1) also states that the man is a robber.